# How to access Object within JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

### Context

If I have the following JSON data:

```
{"response":"success","data":[{"id":"2"}]}
```

I'm trying to get the ID that is sent through, `2`.

### Attempts

I've tried the following:

```
var r = JSON.parse('{"response":"success","data":[{"id":"2"}]}');

if(r.response=="success"){
    var usr = r.data;
    console.log(usr.id);
}
```

The above outputs `undefined`.

---

```
var r = JSON.parse('{"response":"success","data":[{"id":"2"}]}');

if(r.response=="success"){
    var usr = r.data;
    for(var k in usr){
        if(usr.hasOwnProperty(k)){
            console.log(usr.k);
        }
    }
}
```

The above outputs `undefined`.

---

```
var r = JSON.parse('{"response":"success","data":[{"id":"2"}]}');

if(r.response=="success"){
    var usr = r.data;
    var ret = [];
    for(var key in usr){
        ret.push(key);
    }
    console.log(ret);
}
```

The above outputs `0`.

---

```
var r = JSON.parse('{"response":"success","data":[{"id":"2"}]}');

if(r.response=="success"){
    var usr = JSON.parse(r.data);
    console.log(usr.id);
}
```

The above outputs an error - bear in mind this is running via [Nativescript](http://www.nativescript.org) so the simulation environment (Android Emulator) may be causing this error:

> ```
> chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
> 01-26 19:20:55.423  4875  4875 I BrowserStartupController: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
> chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
> 01-26 19:20:55.441  4875  4875 E DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
> chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
> ```

### Question

How can I access the `id` property of `data` in the following JSON string with JavaScript:

```
{"response":"success","data":[{"id":"2"}]}
```

Comment: `r.data[0].id` will get the id

Comment: `data` is an `Array` not an `Object`.

Comment: Thank you both, I understand that now. The reason I thought it was an Object was because when printing it to the console it produces `[object Object]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with following code. You firstly need to access the `data` property and then since `data` is an array, you need an index to access the first elements like data[0] Property and then the `id` property can be retrieved by `r.data[0].id`

```js
var r = JSON.parse('{"response":"success","data":[{"id":"2"}]}');

if(r.response === "success"){
  console.log(r.data[0].id)
  }
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, it doesn't exactly help much without any sort of context.

Comment: @Santi - I was updating the answer, in the time you posted the comment. Does it make it clear now ?

Comment: Much better! +1

Answer (score 1):

You can access `console.log(usr[0].id);`

Answer (score 1):

Your data value is an array not an object

so on your first attempt, update this:

```
console.log(usr.id);
```

to this:

```
console.log(usr[0].id);
```

Or you could do a for loop:

```
if(r.response=="success"){
    var usr = r.data;
    for(i=0; i < usr.length; i++) {
      console.log(usr[i].id);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe9sntqa/)

Answer (score 0):

Your data object is an array, so you must access first to the position of the array:

```
usr[0]
```

the you get the id value

```
usr[0].id
```

If you want to access directly with `usr.id` you need change your JSON data object array to a simple object:

```
{"response":"success","data":{"id":"2"}}
```

or make an ugly reasignation:

```
usr = usr[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have used [] where {} only to be used. If [] is used, then it is an array property, then to access 2, [0].id should be used.

remove [] from [{"id":"2"}]